# I need help to display proper an input label for a date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-form-field` used for a date picker. The problem is that in the new angular 15 the label from `mat-label` goes over the picker icon and is messy. What is a proper solution to "cut" the label and have the "..." up to the icon or any other possible solution to make the control to look nice?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cv9udr?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 200px;">
        <mat-label>Date of Final Loan Payment</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateLoan" readonly formControlName="dateFinalPaymentControl">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateLoan"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dateLoan></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Angular 15? Are you sure is that version released? I just remembered angular 11 only in some months ago. :(

Comment: Yup 15... https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8

Comment: FYI I've created a bug issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26337

Answer (score 0):

Go to the public **styles.scss** file and insert

```
.mat-mdc-floating-label {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The public css is important. Otherwise the style will not working.